# ESS: display-buffer-alist reusable-frames does not work as expected

Tags: buffers, frames, ess

I'm trying to use the `display-buffer-alist` variable to control how Emacs displays spawned inferior shells ([ess-r](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS) in particular).

I'm using the `display-buffer-alist` value from [ess doc](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/doc/ess.texi#L632-L642):

```el
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("*R"
         (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
         (reusable-frames . 0))))
```

However, when I start an `R` shell from some `ess-r-mode` buffer, the `reusable-frames` option does not seem to work: after creating a new frame displaying the `R` shell, Emacs displays a second instance of the `ess-r-mode` buffer in this new frame instead of returning to the old instance.
Everything works correctly when I set `reusable-frames` globally:

```el
(setq display-buffer-reuse-frames 0)
```

but this should not be necessary.

How can I make `display-buffer-alist` work properly without touching global settings?

Versions:

- GNU Emacs 26.1
- Linux 5.4.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.13-1 (2020-01-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Debian bullseye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make `display-buffer-alist` work properly without touching global settings?

The fault here lies not with `display-buffer`, but with the ESS package, specifically the code in [`lisp/ess-inf.el`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-inf.el). You should report this as a bug on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues), quoting the information below.

---

Firstly, `"*R"` is not a valid regexp, as [the asterisk is a special character](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html). In order to match it literally, it should be quoted with a literal backslash. So the correct regexp would be:

```el
(rx "*R") ; => "\\*R"
```

or better yet, to avoid false positives:

```el
(rx bos "*R*") ; => "\\`\\*R\\*"
```

So the correct overall incantation would be:

```el
(setq display-buffer-alist
      `((,(rx bos "*R*")
         (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
         (reusable-frames . 0))))
```

or:

```el
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("\\`\\*R\\*"
         (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
         (reusable-frames . 0))))
```

---

Secondly, the erroneous behaviour you describe happens only the first time one types <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-z</kbd> (`ess-switch-to-inferior-or-script-buffer`) in an `ess-r-mode` buffer, i.e. before the corresponding inferior `*R*` process buffer has been created.

This is because `ess-force-buffer-current` calls `ess-request-a-process` with a non-`nil` `noswitch` argument when an inferior process does not already exist.

`ess-request-a-process`, in turn, does the following as its last step:

```el
(if noswitch
    (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer)) ;; VS: this is weird, but is necessary
  (pop-to-buffer (buffer-name (process-buffer (get-process proc)))))
```

This call to `(pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))` is wrong and is what causes your `ess-r-mode` buffer to appear a second time in the new frame. It was added in the following commit from 2012: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/commit/b29ea8f934f7c08a512c73f14e914bca7229b3c1

I boldly say it is wrong because popping to the current buffer is quite an intrusive operation (as indicated by the bug in question), and the original intention of the author can almost definitely be written in a better way. I don't know what issue the author originally faced, but perhaps the ESS devs can figure it out.

Comment: Please note that when the string starts with a `"*`" it is not interpreted as a regexp. So your initial statements are misleading.

Comment: @LionelHenry Whether a string does or doesn't start with an asterisk does not change how it is interpreted. What determines that, is whether you feed said string to a function expecting a regexp. If you add `"*a[bc]d"` as a `CONDITION` in `display-buffer-alist`, it will match both buffer names `*abd` and `*acd`. So I think my initial statements are valid and your comment is mistaken.

Comment: @LionelHenry If what you meant to say is that a leading asterisk is matched literally, then I think my initial statements remain useful, because that is still an invalid regexp and that behaviour should not be relied upon.

Comment: You're right that it's because an initial asterisk is matched literally and the string is always interpreted as a regexp. It is not an invalid regexp though so your statements are still misleading. I do agree the behaviour should not be relied upon.

Comment: @LionelHenry Only "ordinary characters" match themselves and nothing else; the asterisk is a "special character" - see [`(info "(elisp) Syntax of Regexps")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html).

Comment: @LionelHenry The asterisk "is not a construct by itself; it is a postfix operator", but for "historical compatibility, special characters are treated as ordinary ones if they are in contexts where their special meanings make no sense. [...] It is poor practice to depend on this behavior; quote the special character anyway, regardless of where it appears." - see [`(info "(elisp) Regexp Special")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html).

Comment: @LionelHenry Whether you prefer to call such regexps invalid, wrong, or just bad, my point still stands - users and libraries like ESS alike shouldn't use or advertise them.

Comment: yeah I'd much prefer to call them "bad". Calling them invalid is misleading because they produce valid and deterministic behaviour. It's also misleading in the context of your answer because it's a digression from the main point. With everything else I agree.

Comment: @LionelHenry Using an incorrect historical accident despite being warned against using or relying on it counts as neither "valid" nor "deterministic" in my books. The main point of the OP was how to get `display-buffer-alist` working, so pointing out incorrect regexp usage therein is not a digression as far as I'm concerned. This is a very common Elisp mistake (the ESS manual itself also makes it) that can lead to confusion, so I think it is important to point it out and correct it. Why should good advice be removed from an answer?

Comment: It's a digression because it looks like you're solving their problems when actually they had a different problem. I am stopping this discussion now. Thanks for your answer and bug report anyway!